# Closing ftp stream deletes the uploaded file in c#

Tags: c#, ftp, stream

I have a problem in uploading a multiple files one by one to ftp using stream.
when i try to close the stream(ftpstream.close()) after writing to stream the file uploaded gets deleted. 
If I don't use the .close(),few file gets uploaded but for the third call to getstreamrequest()(which gets called for each file upload) gives "This operation is timed out error"

```
 using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath)))
                        {

                            stream.Position = 0;
                            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            string uri = String.Format("{0}/{1}", _FTPURL, fileName);


                            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));

                            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_FTPUSRNAME, _FTPPSWD);
                            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                            request.KeepAlive = false;
                            request.UseBinary = true;
                            request.UsePassive = true;
                            request.ContentLength = stream.Length;
                            request.EnableSsl = false;

                            int bufferLength = 2048*20;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                            int contentLength;

                            ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();


                            contentLength = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                            while (contentLength != 0)
                            {
                                ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
                                contentLength = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                            }                                
                        }
                     pageNo++;

                    }
                }
                ftpStream.Close();
            }
            while (!hasPaginationCompleted);
```

Comment: Code shown in the post (`stream(ftpstream.close())`) is very strange. Please provide [MCVE] so one can suggest what is wrong with your code. (Second half of your post is by design as there is default limit on simultaneous open connections).

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-use-c-to-upload-and-download-files-from-an-ftp-server/) may help

Answer (score 1):

I think what is wrong in your code is the place where you call `ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();` and where you close the stream with `ftpStream.Close();`

lot's of `}` are in between and this would mean you are getting multiple request streams without closing them correctly.

You may need to close the stream in the same code level as where you request it.

Comment: my code this kind do{     } while(!hasPaginationCompleted) ... after do am placing ftpstream.close() ....if i place after while (contentLength != 0) { } also gives same error... no matter where i place .close() as soon as its execute the uploaded file gets deleted...